# Can react-native share codebase with Proton native?

Tags: react-native, electron, proton-native

I'm working on the mobile app with react native, and going to start on the desktop version. Im considering proton native because it uses the same syntax as react native does, and its size and  starting duration are way much better than Electron.

Im wondering if proton native and react native can share the same codebase, since they both using the same syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my project.
In my mind, you can share `react-native` project sources to `proton-native`.
We just need to stick together :)